# Remove duplicate string in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, duplicates

i'm new to c++ and i'm looking for a way to remove duplicate strings from an array of strings that looks like this:
`string exempleArray[]= {"string1", "string2", "string1"};`
after the code it should look like this: 
`"string1", "string2"`,
but the order doesn't matter at all. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 4):

If the order doesn't matter, you can first sort the array with `std::sort`, then use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) to remove the duplicates.

```
std::sort(std::begin(exampleArray), std::end(exampleArray));
auto it = std::unique(std::begin(exampleArray), std::end(exampleArray));
```

Here, `it` points to one past the end of the new, unique range. Note that since you started with a fixed size array, you cannot reduce its size to the number of unique elements. You would need to copy the elements to a container whose size can be determined at runtime. `std::vector<std:string>` is an obvious candidate.

```
std::vector<std::string> unique_strings(std::begin(exampleArray), it);
```

Note if you started with an `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a fixed size array, you would be able to avoid the copy and remove elements from the original vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings = {"string1" "string2" "string1"};
std::sort(strings);
auto it = std::unique(std::begin(strings), std::end(strings));
strings.erase(it, strings.end());
```

Comment: Cant you avoid `std::copy`? Why not prefer constructor as `std::vector<std::string> unique_strings{std::begin(exampleArray), it};`? Any specific reason?

Comment: @Nawaz of course thanks! That would be the obvious way to do it. For whatever reason it didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want this, then prefer storing them in a `std::set` instead. It will automatically store unique items.

Or if you have array (or `std::vector`) already and cannot use `std::set` for some reason, then make use of `std::sort` *followed by* `std::unique` to achieve that.